# Захватить файл в монопольное пользование

Tags: c#, filestream

На шаре лежит файл с `DateTime`.

На разных серверах крутятся 2 (или более) инстансов одного и того же приложения, которые обращаются на шару к файлу, забирают из него время и записывают новое время.

Я использую

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(dateFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

А затем считываю время и пытаюсь перезаписать новое время с помощью

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
```

Но такое использование приводит к *дописывнию*, а не *перезаписыванию* файла.

1. Как организовать монопольный доступ к файлу, чтобы никто другой не мог прочитать из него информацию (и изменить тем более)?
2. Как перезаписывать файл? (Здесь вероятно нужно с помощью `fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` и без использования класса `StreamWriter`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(dateFile, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
```

---

Я неправильно прочитал Ваш вопрос, Вы считываете время, тогда нужно так:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(dateFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
```

Этот код должен выставлять позицию записи в начало файла, и не должно быть проблем с перезаписью значения. Но, что вероятно, если Вы сначала читаете, а потом пишете, то позиция потока будет смещена, поэтому после того, как прочитали старое значение выставляйте позицию в начало: `fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` и уже после этого создавайте поток на запись(`StreamWriter`).

Comment: Угу, `FileShare.ReadWrite` означает Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing

Comment: А в этом случае я же не смогу считать значение до его изменения из-за `FileMode.Truncate`. Или я не понял этого мода?

Comment: @VladislavVitalyev, обновил ответ

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Я так понимаю, в таком случае второй инстанс будет получать IOException, который я легко могу обработать как `Thread.Sleep(5000)` и повторную попытку обращения к файлу.

Comment: @VladislavVitalyev, да, всё так. Но я бы не стал так долго ждать. У Вас же операция довольно быстрая, можно попробовать вообще не ждать, а сразу пробовать опять.